# Why does this method get called twice when button is clicked?

Tags: java, methods, combobox, applet

I am building a simple applet and in my applet I have a combo box with a drop down list. When an option is selected, and a button "add" is clicked, the selection is take and pass to a method that creates an object. The only problem is that when I click the button, it adds the object fine, but then when I try adding another slelection, it deletes the previous one and sets the new one equal to the same attributes as the new one. So in essence it is re adding the selection.

```
btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                addTooObj(comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString(), lblStatusLabel);
                System.out.println(comboBox.getSelectedIndex());

            }

        });



 private void addToobj(String num,JLabel j){
        System.out.println(num);
        Object objToBeAdded = null;
        long objNumber = Long.parseLong(num);
        int quan = 0;
        if (objNumber == 12354589621l) {
            objToBeAdded = new Item(objNumber, 2.00, quan);
        } else if (objNumber == 21) {
            objToBeAdded = new Item(objNumber, 1.50, quan);
        } else if (objNumber == 12) {
            objToBeAdded = new Item(objNumber, 5.20, quan);
        } else {
            System.out.println("error");
        }

         oldObj.add(objToBeAdded);
     }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) - this won't even compile `private void addToobj(num){` - so how should we know you're actually showing the code that's causing your problem.

Comment: Still won't compile, your calling the method with two parameters, it only expects one.

Comment: opps. Sorry. That was a typo on my behalf. Its a lot of code, and I didn't want to copy and paste everything..

Answer (score 0):

Within your `actionPerformed` method, you could get the action command and review what actions it is been fired for and then only call your method if the action is the action you want.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     String action = e.getActionCommand();
     System.out.println("The action was: " + action);
     if(action.equals("What ever action you want")){
         addTooObj(comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString(), lblStatusLabel);
         System.out.println(comboBox.getSelectedIndex());
     }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Right, after re reading the question I see it wouldn't have. What is oldObj?